# How to right align text in Navigation Bar - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So I just recently started practicing HTML and CSS on my own time. I just started building a website using bootstrap and I'm having trouble with this navigation bar: [navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtQGA.png) You can find it on this webstie: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ 
and scroll down to "Nav" (i dont know how to include HTML code here)

What I want to do is have the items "Home" "Features" "Pricing" and "Disabled" "Search" (A search bar that I will implement) floating to the right. Eventually I will have something like:

NavBar-----------------------------------------------------------------Home Features Pricing Disabled #Search

But I can't seem to do it. I've tried to use span tags, ul tags, I've tried to remove some div elements but nothing is working. Any help?

Also I have a question. If I put:
    "Navbar"
inside a div, then it is still inline with the rest of the nav elements (Home, Pricing etc...) which are in a different div. How is that possible? 
Aren't divs block elements?

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets along with your question. Code snippets in external links are discouraged in SO.

Comment: Use the class `ml-auto` in your `<ul>`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8Lmkhoyb/

Comment: Andrew L I just did. @Chris G okay so that worked ! I'm not sure I get why it worked though. Can you explain? Why couldn't I just do float: right under ul? I used <ul class="navbar-nav"> instead of <div class="navbar-nav"> in line 7.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't use float for that, curiously (I had no idea). It uses `margin-left: auto`, which has the same effect. The class to apply that is `ml-auto`, as described here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn and use [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

It is a very powerful css layout library that is supported by most browsers.

Check out an example here for the Nav Bar.  There are many ways you can right align.  One way is to have an empty element just to the left of the nav elements that takes up remaining space which pushes the elements all the way to the right.

To achieve this for the Bootstrap example

[image]

All I did was add

```
<div style="flex-grow: 1;"></div>
```

Right below

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

And right above

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
```

Comment: pretty sure you meant ml-auto on that last line. Thanks !

Comment: @user7552492 You can use `ml-auto`, it just applies a margin left.  This is an alternate way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking to use Bootstrap features, you can achieve this by wrapping your links with this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <links>
</ul>
```

Without using bootstrap:

```css
.align-left { float: left }
.align-right { float: right }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="align-left">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse align-right" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks ! care to show me how to do it without bootstrap features?

Comment: @user7552492 Sure, there you go, fully functional without Bootstrap positioning. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem, thanks!

Comment: Hey, the part without using bootstrap doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: @user7552492 You need to make sure the `clear: both;` is outside of the `div`s you're trying to float, and you need to apply the CSS classes to the HTML as I've done in mine. Also, make sure to add `;` at the end of the CSS parameter if you have multiple rules in a single class. (It works in my code without `;` since there is only one thing happening in the `{ }`.

Comment: I did all of that but for some reason it doesn't work on my code. I guess I'll just settle for ml-auto. By the way, the code you gave me on how to do this with bootstrap features doesn't work either. only ml-auto works

Comment: @user7552492 It must have changed from v3.3 - v4. Strange how the non-bootstrap doesn't work. It works in the code snippet I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `mr-auto` to fix the elements to the right.

Your code will become :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```